# trouble in with reverse viewing/search function in double linked list C programming

Tags: c, linked-list

hey guys this is my first time doing double linked list so I'm not very sure what I'm doing here ,need some help to check the code,thanks, here is what I have done with comments included.
The functions I have done here are print,print reverse,count elements in the linked list,and search function to determine whether this node exist

```
 void printListfow() //print the list in forward manner
{
    CLR;
    struct node *tmpval; //declare a temp storage
    if(start==NULL) //if 1st node = null,then nth is inside,nth to print
    {
         printf("List is empty\n");
         return; 
    }
     tmpval=start; //assign the head/start to temp storage to retrieve data in 1st node
     printf("List of customer details: \n");
     while(tmpval!=NULL) //keep doing till it is NULL/the end
     {
         printf("%d ", tmpval->detail); //print the 'detail' which is in the node temp is pointing at
         tmpval=tmpval->next; //assign next node to the temp storage so that it can be printed again
     }

}


void printListrev() //print in reverse manner
{
      CLR;
      struct node *tmpval; //temp storage
      if(start==NULL) //
      {
          printf("List is empty\n");
          return;
      }
      tmpval=start; //assign start to tmpval to retrieve value
      printf("List of customer details: \n");
      tmpval=tmpval->prev //move backward and assign the data to tmpval
      printf("%d",tmpval->detail) //print it

}

void count() //count total number of records
{   struct node *x;
    x=start; //assign value of start to temp storage
    int ctr=0; //initialize counter
    while(x!=NULL) 
  {
    x=x->next; //keep going to next node and then increase the counter
    ctr++;
  }
  printf("Number of customer records are %d\n",ctr);
}



int getNode(node *tmp ,int cust) //when user wants to delete a customer ID and its details, this will search through the list,then if found,pass the value to another function for deletion
{
    tmp=tmp->cust; 
    while(tmp!=NULL)
    {
        if(tmp->detail == cust) //check if detail[ID stored] is same as requested[cust]
        {
            return 1;
        }tmp=tmp->next; //if not same,then move to next one
    }return 0;

}
```

thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is more appropriate for: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: in `printListrev()` you forgot to add loop to travel back I think! ??

Comment: you should post struct node declaration too

Comment: If the list is circular (as you use e.g. `start->prev` to get to the last node), then when you loop forward will not the `next` pointer of the last node point to `start` leading to infinite looping?

Comment: You don't show how the list is built: `start->prev` would normally be null unless it is a circular list (and then a null check to find the end doesn't work) - do you have an `end` variable and you meant `end->prev`?

Comment: If you have start (head of your list) you could implement end (tail of your list) in your code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In context to `printListrev()`:

Unless this is a circular doubly linked list, in which case last element is preceded by the first, `start` would have previous element NULL. So, there is no point in accessing the previous field of `start`, as you do here:

```
tmpval=start;
...
tmpval=tmpval->prev;
```

You can keep another pointer to end of the list for this purpose.

Other alternatives include:

recursive function:

```
void printrev(struct node *s)
{
    if (s == NULL)
    return;
    printrev(s->next);
    printf("%d ", s->detail);
}
```

iterative function:

```
void printrev()
{
    struct node *end;
    for (end = start; end->next != NULL; end = end->next)
    ;
    for (; end != NULL; end = end->prev)
    printf("%d ", end->detail);
}
```

Your `getNode` is of limited use. Suppose, if you want to delete element, your `getnode` would only return whether, element is present or not. Say it is present, your `deleteNode` function would still have to iterate to the appropriate element in the list before deleting it.

This could be solved by `getNode` returning pointer to the node:

```
node *getNode(int x)
{
    node *t;
    for (t = start; t != NULL; t = t->next)
        if (t->detail == x)
                return t;
    return t;
}
```

Now, you can code delete as follows:

```
void delNode(node *n)
{
    n->prev->next = n->next;
    n->next->prev = n->prev;
    free(n);
}
```

And call as follows:

```
node *n;

if ((n = getNode(x)) != NULL)
    delNode(n);
```

I've assumed that you `struct` is:

```
struct node {
    int detail;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *right;
};

typedef struct node * node;
```

Comment: difference between recursive and iterative??

Comment: A recursive function, solves first sub-problem of size n-1, which does nothing but print all n-1 elements recursively, and then prints the nth element. Thus the final order is reversed. That's quite similar to stack. It'll first push n, then n-1 ... 1, so on. Now, each element is popped and printed. So, the order becomes 1, 2...n, reverse of the original order

Comment: On the other hand iterative function, just iterates to end of the list. Then, iterates again to the beginning, printing all elements in between.

Comment: so the recursive print in reverse while iterative keeps looping?

Comment: also bro any idea how can I fix the getNode function?? thanks

Comment: What do you intend to do with `getNode` function?

Comment: this functions checks whether the node exists in the linked list, let's say if it doesn't exist then I will tell user it does not exist,else I will tell it exists, also I wanna link this to other function,such as deletion, so if it doesn't exist,then I cannot proceed,else I can delete the node

Comment: i've completed my delete function,thanks anwyway,thanks a lot for the getnode,that's what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

- In printListrev() you are printing only one node not going reverse.
- One major problem you  are doing is in getNode() ,you are changing the address of a local pointer but the original pointer still points where it previously.
- If so then how you are going to delete that node ,as you can't know the node address after this function returns.
- Are you going to call the getNode() for all the node ,if so that is not a good if you have many nodes.